# OSError with Pybluez librairy

Tags: python, bluetooth, raspberry-pi, pybluez

I would like to make a bluetooth communication between a laptop  with a bluetooth dongle and windows 7, and my raspberry pi 3.

I found on internet some tutorials which use the Pybluez librairy but this doesn't work for me.

Find below the code for the server part :

```
import bluetooth

Host = ""
port = 12

HostAddr = (Host, port)

def setupServer():
    server_socket=bluetooth.BluetoothSocket( bluetooth.RFCOMM )
    print("Socket Created.")
    server_socket.bind(HostAddr)
    server_socket.listen(1)
    print("Socket bind complete")

    client_sock, client_info = server_socket.accept()
    print("Accepted connection from " , client_info)

    try:
        while True:
            data = client_sock.recv(1024)
            if len(data) == 0: break
            print("received [%s]" %data)
    except IOError:
        pass

    print("Disconnected")

client_sock.close()
server_socket.close()
print("all done")
```

setupServer()

This is the output :

```
Socket Created.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path_to_file\Server.py", line 33, in <module>
setupServer()
  File "path_to_file\Server.py", line 12, in setupServer
server_socket.bind(HostAddr)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\bluetooth\msbt.py", line 60, in bind
bt.bind (self._sockfd, addr, port)
OSError
```

Do you have an idea why i had this error ?

Comment: Either: is port 12 available? use netstat, see if anything is already bound to port 12. Or: have you tried putting "0.0.0.0." in Host variable?

Comment: There is nothing on port 12 so it seem to be available. I also tried to put "0.0.0.0" or the MAC Address of my dongle but i always have the same error.

Comment: Are you running the script using sudo?

Comment: Yes for sure ..